# Setting HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName to Development in Rider

Tags: .net, .net-core, rider

My code:

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(
                (hostContext, configApp) =>
                {
                    configApp.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
                    configApp.AddJsonFile(
                        $"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json",
                        optional: true);
                })
            .Build();

        await host.RunAsync();
    }
```

In runtime I see that the value of `HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName` is `Production`.

I tried to set the following environment variable in running configuration, but it didn't change the runtime: `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`.

Where can I configure it?

Comment: Have you had a chance to review the following in docs yet https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2#set-the-environment

Comment: There's a way to set environment variables directly from Rider using [launch settings profiles](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Run_Debug_Configuration_dotNet_Launch_Settings_Profile.html#editing-launch-settings-profiles). No need to create a System wide Environment Variable to run or debug project in Rider. And you may switch between many profiles for different environments quickly and easily.

Answer (score 9):

Adding the following solved the issue, I figured it after debugging with decompiled .NET source. It doesn't seem documented anywhere, or I'm missing something.

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost => configHost.AddEnvironmentVariables())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(
                (hostContext, configApp) =>
                {
                    configApp.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
                    configApp.AddJsonFile(
                        $"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json",
                        optional: true);
                })
            .Build();

        await host.RunAsync();
    }
```

The added line is `ConfigureHostConfiguration` call.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#host-configuration-1

Comment: Yes, I read all of this doc. Its misguiding. See this snippet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configureappconfiguration , that's the one I used. It simply doesn't work without calling `ConfigureHostConfiguration` first, which is not mentioned in this doc as far as I could find.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I can see how that can get confusing fast. Glad you found a solution to your problem. Happy Coding.